# DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, resource) return null

Tags: android, android-databinding

I started using Android Data binding but without success.I have done everything as proposed in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) but when I have to set method value I get null.
I am using Android Studio 2.1.2 and I put in gradle

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

in layout I do exactly da same put layout and inside I put tag data:

```
<data>
    <variable name="order" type="com.example.Order"/>
</data>
```

and in code when I want to have binding variable

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
ActivityOrderOnePaneBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_order_one_pane);
binding.setOrder(mOrder);
```

Binding is null,I don't have compile errors.

Comment: Did you use `layout` as root element of the layout file?

Comment: Yes I did and android makes classes and everything I dont have any complie error so I can run without any problems

Comment: can you post your code of `onCreate()`?

Comment: setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            ActivityOrderOnePaneBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_order_one_pane);
            binding.setOrder(mOrder);

Comment: I think you might be getting null pointer for `mOrder` not for `binding`

Comment: @RRR variables are nullable

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void package.databinding.ActivityOrderOnePaneBinding.setOrder(package.Order)' on a null object reference. if I check binding == null result is TRUE, so its not a problem on mOrder variable.

Comment: The problem is I am extending this activity from class where is setContentView overrided, now I remove extend and its working. So my question is simple Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're overriding `setContentView` in your `Activity`, you need to replace:

```
ActivityOrderOnePaneBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_order_one_pane);
```

with

```
ActivityOrderOnePaneBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), R.layout.activity_order_one_pane, getContentFrame(), false);
setContentView(binding.getRoot());
```

I had the same problem because I overrode `setContentView` in my base `Activity` and that fixed it.

If you overrode `setContentView`, `getContentFrame()` is the `ViewGroup` that contains your content, exclusive of the `AppBarLayout` and `Toolbar`. Here's an example of what `getContentFrame()` would look like if you had a base layout similar to what's below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        ...>
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
           ...>
                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                   .../>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`getContentFrame()` just returns the `FrameLayout` in the above layout.

```
protected ViewGroup getContentFrame() {
    return (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: can't find definition of `getContentFrame( )`

Comment: @MarvinEffing I updated my answer to show the possible content of `getContentFrame()`.

Comment: still getting null in binding variable

Comment: @akshaybhange did you override `setContentView`? If you didn't, maybe a different solution would work for you.

Comment: FrameLyaout helped, but I also had to set R.layout.my_content(with layout root element) and not R.layout.activity as a parameter to inflate method.

Comment: Just try to clean and rebuild. setContentView() will also work. I tested it today with target 29

Answer (score 3):

Try to rebuild gradle and clean project

Comment: This is the real solution

Comment: That's right. And better remove the previous installed application.