# DataBindingUtil must not return null when launched from ApplicationTest

Tags: android, data-binding, android-espresso, android-databinding, android-uiautomator

binding is NULL when running "ApplicationTest" but is correct when running "app". [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892346/databindingutil-setcontentviewthis-resource-return-null) doesn't work.

**ApplicationTest**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ApplicationTest {

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<LoadingActivity> mActivityRule =
        new ActivityTestRule<>(LoadingActivity.class);

@Test
public void loginClickMarkerAndUploadDamageReport() {
    UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
    //Some initialization code, and then LoginActivity gets started by the App

//This works..
onView(withId(R.id.user_email)).perform(replaceText("some@mail.com"));  

    }
}
```

**LoginActivity**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final LoginActivityBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_login);
    }
}
```

**activity_login**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="dataSource"
            type="nl.brandmkrs.damageapp.model.User" />
    </data>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:id="@+id/user_email"
        android:text="@{dataSource.password}"/>
</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

**build.gradle**

```
defaultConfig { 
     minSdkVersion 17
     targetSdkVersion 25
     testInstrumentationRunner     
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
productFlavors {
    // The actual application flavor
    production {
        minSdkVersion 17
    }
    // Test application flavor for UIAutomator tests
    uiTest {
        minSdkVersion 18
    }
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

[image]

**Output:**

*E/MonitoringInstrumentation: Exception encountered by: nl.brandmkrs.damageapp.view.LoginActivity@d8d4afd. Dumping thread state to outputs and pining for the fjords.
                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.VideoView nl.brandmkrs.damageapp.databinding.LoginActivityBinding.videoView' on a null object reference
                                                                  at nl.brandmkrs.damageapp.view.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:96)*

Comment: Do you have `testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"` in your gradle and run configuration?

Comment: yes I have it in my build.gradle.

Comment: Have you tried starting LoginActivity directly from the test.  Does it also return a null?

Comment: yes it does return null. But, it used to work and I'm not interested in starting LoginActivity directly

Comment: Could you post your complete `onCreate()` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating

```
classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.4.0'
```

Solved the problem...

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I'm not using retrolambda. Are you sure that this fixed it or could it have been something else?